# How to repair a mailbox with public folders?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, public-folders, data-integrity

We have an Exchange 2013 organization with sort of legacy public folder set transferred via import/export from Exchange 2003 times. It has several linked mailboxes for our staff, and several dozens of public folders stuffed into a single PF mailbox to use in established business processes.

We have a constant problem that occasionally a user with linked mailbox loses connection to Exchange public folders, while retaining normal functionality of their mailbox. This happens across all the organization without actually narrowing the problem to anything. We have even raised an incident with Microsoft support regarding this problem, they exhausted second line support and requested payment for future investigation - we declined.

Eventually we have exhausted all the possible sources of connectivity loss except a weird bug in Exchange or mailbox corruption, but built-in `New-MailboxRepairRequest` cmdlet that's available to repair single mailboxes seems to skip the mailbox with public folders. Repairing the database is possible, but it will stall our business processes for long enough to cause money loss, so this is out of question, and normal mailboxes are apparently healthy. Is there an ability to repair a public folder mailbox without forcing a database repair? Also, will database repair actually process a public folder mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

Not confirm but you can give try to exchange recovery solutions, here is a list: http://www.msexchange.org/software/Backup-Recovery/

If a move request for a public folder or public folder mailbox fails, you can restore the folder or mailbox as long as the following conditions apply:

Failed public folder move  -  A soft-deleted copy of the public folder still exists in the source public folder mailbox and is still within the retention period.

Failed public folder mailbox move  -  A soft-deleted copy of the public folder mailbox still exists in the source mailbox database and is still within the mailbox retention period.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj983802(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Hmm, is it true that a simple move of a public folder mailbox will at least detect for corruption?